# Stuck with Java json exception

Tags: java, json, exception

Background: Have collected tweets from the streaming api to a textfile and successfully parsed each line to my java objects using json.org library. Great.

Problem: From the "text": -field I want to extract information, this works semi-good. I do however get this exception running my code:

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 1280 [character 1281 line 1]
```

Trying to locate where in my textfile this is, I only see regular characters and with the mindset that json.org lib does what it's supposed to do, why am I getting this? Where do I even begin?

This is line 1280 in my file. Character 1281 is a 'o' so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

> {"retweet_count":null,"text":"Listening to Don't Get Me Wrong by Pretenders on @Grooveshark: http:\/\/tinysong.com\/o9ui #musicmonday #nowplaying","id_str":"28756412823","entities":{"urls":[{"indices":[63,87],"expanded_url":null,"url":"http:\/\/tinysong.com\/o9ui"}],"hashtags":[{"text":"musicmonday","indices":[88,100]},{"text":"nowplaying","indices":[101,112]}],"user_mentions":[{"id_str":"3806441","indices":[49,61],"screen_name":"Grooveshark","name":"Grooveshark","id":3806441}]},"coordinates":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"place":null,"geo":null,"new_id_str":"608552371148029952","source":"web","new_id":608552371148029952,"truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"favorited":false,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"created_at":"Tue Oct 26 03:40:05 +0000 2010","contributors":null,"user":{"follow_request_sent":null,"lang":"en","time_zone":"La Paz","id_str":"24490174","following":null,"profile_text_color":"666666","followers_count":466,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a3.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/113185343\/x0f8a90fc4af7484f7a0c6c11d594f94.png","profile_link_color":"3399CC","description":"I'm a complex being. A bit of a nerd and a geek with social skills, as unlikely as that may sound. Active gamer. Lover of music, movies, books and food. ","listed_count":18,"notifications":null,"profile_background_tile":true,"statuses_count":17095,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"202020","profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1117295836\/geekydot2_normal.jpg","location":"Dominican Republic","show_all_inline_media":false,"profile_use_background_image":false,"contributors_enabled":false,"friends_count":339,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"666666","protected":false,"screen_name":"dotina","geo_enabled":false,"created_at":"Sun Mar 15 05:06:39 +0000 2009","name":"Ligia Carri\u00f3n","favourites_count":0,"url":"http:\/\/geekydot.wordpress.com\/","id":24490174,"verified":false,"utc_offset":-14400,"profile_background_color":"202020"},"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"id":28756412823}

and here's the same thing, formatted:

```
{
    "retweet_count": null,
    "text": "Listening to Don't Get Me Wrong by Pretenders on @Grooveshark: http:\/\/tinysong.com\/o9ui #musicmonday #nowplaying",
    "id_str": "28756412823",
    "entities": {
        "urls": [
            {
                "indices": [
                    63,
                    87
                ],
                "expanded_url": null,
                "url": "http:\/\/tinysong.com\/o9ui"
            }
        ],
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "text": "musicmonday",
                "indices": [
                    88,
                    100
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "nowplaying",
                "indices": [
                    101,
                    112
                ]
            }
        ],
        "user_mentions": [
            {
                "id_str": "3806441",
                "indices": [
                    49,
                    61
                ],
                "screen_name": "Grooveshark",
                "name": "Grooveshark",
                "id": 3806441
            }
        ]
    },
    "coordinates": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "geo": null,
    "new_id_str": "608552371148029952",
    "source": "web",
    "new_id": 608552371148029952,
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "created_at": "Tue Oct 26 03:40:05 +0000 2010",
    "contributors": null,
    "user": {
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "lang": "en",
        "time_zone": "La Paz",
        "id_str": "24490174",
        "following": null,
        "profile_text_color": "666666",
        "followers_count": 466,
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/a3.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/113185343\/x0f8a90fc4af7484f7a0c6c11d594f94.png",
        "profile_link_color": "3399CC",
        "description": "I'm a complex being. A bit of a nerd and a geek with social skills, as unlikely as that may sound. Active gamer. Lover of music, movies, books and food. ",
        "listed_count": 18,
        "notifications": null,
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "statuses_count": 17095,
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "202020",
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1117295836\/geekydot2_normal.jpg",
        "location": "Dominican Republic",
        "show_all_inline_media": false,
        "profile_use_background_image": false,
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "friends_count": 339,
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "666666",
        "protected": false,
        "screen_name": "dotina",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "created_at": "Sun Mar 15 05:06:39 +0000 2009",
        "name": "Ligia Carri\u00f3n",
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "url": "http:\/\/geekydot.wordpress.com\/",
        "id": 24490174,
        "verified": false,
        "utc_offset": -14400,
        "profile_background_color": "202020"
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "id": 28756412823
}
```

Comment: I'd start by removing stuff from your JSON to make it a lot smaller. To try and isolate the error and once you have slimmed it down to only have the section that causes the error I'd update your post here with that.

Comment: what JSON are you using to parse twitter response? also, are you using any twitter api?

Comment: @TEG: I'm using the library from http://www.json.org/java/index.html I'll be looking into removing stuff but I'm working with a ~20K lines text file for very basic extraction and analysis of the parts of the tweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try another parser which could give you better error message.

Error itself suggests that this would occur within a JSON Object, after value, in which case it should be either followed by a comma separating following value, or '}' to end object.
It is possible that line number could be off (which would be a bug). That's why it would be good to try to either indent input for testing (to get more accurate location) or to try smaller snippets.